# Linearized Einstein Field equation in general background

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, resource-recommendations, curvature, linearized-theory

I am trying to compute Linearzed Einstein Field equation in general background.

I mean $g_{\mu\nu} = \bar{g}_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$ and compute R, $R_{\mu\nu}$ and so on.

I realized the computation is quite handy, and I even don't know my computation is right or not.

Is there any reference for metric perturbation in general background?

Comment: It is done in Straumann's book

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here - https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/487808/133418

Comment: @Avantgarde Thanks! After confirming the first order computation by hand I will use xPert for higher-order computation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many topics in general relativity, Wald gives a fairly good treatment of the general case in his book "General Relativity", in this case in section 7.5.

It is one of the few "standard texts" in GR I found that actually treats the general case. Many others (e.g. MTW) restrict to perturbations of flat space, or immediately specialize to black hole perturbation theory.