# Linearized gravity in BTZ black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, linearized-theory

I'm currently studying [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05687) on traversable wormholes in an eternal BTZ black hole. In the first pages the authors say that is instructive to check that a small spherically symmetric perturbation of the stress tensor $T_{\mu\nu}∼ O(\epsilon)$ results in a traversable wormhole exactly when the ANEC is violated ($\int T_{\mu\nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu}d\lambda<0$), by solving the linearized Einstein equation for $h_{\mu\nu}$. Doing so in Kruskal coordinates, I should be able to find, at $V=0$, the fairly simple

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{l^2}(h_{UU}+\partial_U(Uh_{UU}))-r_h^{-2}\partial_U^{2}h_{\phi\phi}\right]=8\pi G_NT_{UU}.
\end{equation}

I worked out the BTZ metric (with $J=0$) in Kruskal coordinates, which turns out to be
\begin{equation}
ds^2=-4l^2\dfrac{dUdV}{(1+UV)^2}+r_h^2\dfrac{(1-UV)^2}{(1+UV)^2}d\phi^2.
\end{equation}
with $|UV|<1$.
I wasn't familiar with linearized gravity in a curved background, so I checked the theory on Wald's General Relativity, adjusting the treatment in presence of both a stress tensor and a non-null cosmological constant $\Lambda$. I also found [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/487777/) which gives me the Ricci tensor up to $O(h^3)$. Still, I have issues with the explicit computation, mostly because of the generic expression of $h_{\mu\nu}$. I know that it must be spherically symmetric, but in Kruskal coordinates all I can say is that $h_{V\phi}=h_{U\phi}=0$. This leaves me with five non-null components (four of which are independent), namely $h_{UU}, h_{VV}, h_{\phi\phi}, h_{UV}$. The form of the Ricci tensor that comes out is still completely unaccessible and setting $V=0$ doesn't help.

In polar coordinates I know the form of the most general spherically symmetric metric. Is there a way to find something similar for Kruskal coordinates, or the components I listed above are all a priori non zero? Can I say something about their coordinate expression, apart from the fact that they cannot depend on $\phi$?