# Gauge invariance of linearized gravity with an arbitrary background spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gauge-invariance, linearized-theory

Consider here a background metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, we impose a perturbation $g_{\mu\nu}+\epsilon h_{\mu\nu}$ with $\epsilon\ll1$. Then we can write down the modified Einstein-Hilbert action with zero cosmological constant:
\begin{align}
 S&=\int\mathrm{d}^{D}x\sqrt{-g}\left(1-\epsilon\frac{1}{2}h_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}\right)\left(R^{0}+\epsilon R^{1}\right)\\
&=S^{0}+\epsilon\int\mathrm{d}^{D}x\sqrt{-g}\left(R^{1}-\frac{1}{2}R^{0}g_{\mu\nu}h^{\mu\nu}\right)+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)\, 
\end{align}
where $R^{0}$ is the Ricci scalar w.r.t $g_{\mu\nu}$, and $R^{1}$ is the correction of $R$ at the leading order which can be found in this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/487808).

To my knowledge, if for any: $$\delta_{\zeta}h_{\mu\nu}=\nabla_{\mu}\zeta_{\nu}+\nabla_{\nu}\zeta_{\mu}=\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}g_{\mu\nu} \, \ \ \ \delta_{\zeta}g_{\mu\nu}=0 \,$$ the action is invariant at each order, this theory is gauge invariant, and the perturbation field $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a spin-2 gauge field. For example, when the background is flat $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}$,  $R^{0}=0$, one can check this easily, for an arbitrary $\zeta \ $:
\begin{align}
\delta_{\zeta}S&=\delta_{\zeta}S^0+\epsilon\int\mathrm{d}^{D}x\sqrt{-g}\delta_{\zeta}R^{1}
+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)\\
&=0.
\end{align}
But for a curved background $R^{0}\ne 0$, in principle one should show whether: $$\int\mathrm{d}^Dx\sqrt{-g}\left(\delta_{\zeta}R^{1}-\frac{1}{2}R^{0}g_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}g^{\mu\nu}\right)=0 \ .$$ According to the P4 eq(2.4) in this paper [2110.13512](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.13512.pdf), one find
\begin{equation}
\delta_{\zeta}R^{1}=\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}R^{0}.
\end{equation}
Thus, for any $g_{\mu\nu}$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}R-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}g^{\mu\nu}&=\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}(g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu})-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}g^{\mu\nu}\\
&=g^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}R_{\mu\nu}+\left[R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}\right]\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}g^{\mu\nu}\\
&=g^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}R_{\mu\nu}+\mathrm{EoM}\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}g^{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
if $g_{\mu\nu}$ is a solution of field equation, the gauge invariance of a linearized theory if and only if $\delta_{\zeta}R^1_{\mu\nu}=\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}R^0_{\mu\nu}=0$, as expected. But it is not easy to calculate. So on the other hand, we express it as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}R-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}g^{\mu\nu}&=\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}R+\frac{1}{2}Rg^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}_{\zeta}g_{\mu\nu}\\
&=\zeta^\mu\nabla_\mu R+R\nabla_\mu\zeta^\mu\\
&=\nabla_\mu(\zeta^\mu R)
\end{align}
**This equation states that a theory is gauge invariant if and only if $\zeta^\mu R^{0}\big|_{\partial\mathcal{M}}=0$. This result is suspicious to me, is something wrong here?**

Especially, for $dS$ spacetime, this boundary term is non-zero. So is there a gauge-invariant linearized theory in $dS$?

Answer (score 0):

### Gauge symmetry for a linearized theory

Consider a gravity theory allowing a cosmological constant described by the Hilbert-Einstein action
$$S[g]=\int_\mathcal{M}\mathrm{d}^nx\sqrt{-g}\left(R-2\Lambda\right)\, ,$$
which is invariant under an arbitrary diffeomorphism transformation
$$x^\mu\rightarrow x^\mu+\xi^\mu(x)\, ,$$
but usually, a distinct viewpoint attributing all transformations on the field is more useful
$$g_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow g_{\mu\nu}+(\nabla_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}+\nabla_{\nu}\xi_{\mu})\, .$$
Now we divide the whole spacetime metric into two parts
$$g_{\mu\nu}+\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}+ h_{\mu\nu}\, ,$$
where we set $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$ as a background field,  which is fixed thus with no dynamics - a given solution of field equation,
$$S^\prime[h]=S[h+\bar{g}]\, .$$
Thus the theory of $h_{\mu\nu}$ inherits the diffeomorphism symmetry from the whole theory of $g_{\mu\nu}$, i.e. under
\begin{align}
\delta_\xi \bar{g}_{\mu\nu}&=0\\
\delta_\xi h_{\mu\nu}&=\nabla_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}+\nabla_{\nu}\xi_{\mu}\, \\
&=\bar{\nabla}_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}+\bar{\nabla}_{\nu}\xi_{\mu}-2\delta\Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \mu\nu}\xi_\rho\, ,\\
&=\bar{\nabla}_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}+\bar{\nabla}_{\nu}\xi_{\mu}+\mathcal{O}(h\xi)\\
\delta\Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \mu\nu}&=\frac{1}{2}[\bar{\nabla}_\mu h_{\nu}^{\ \rho}+\bar{\nabla}_\nu h_{\mu}^{\ \rho}-\bar{\nabla}^\rho h_{\mu\nu}]\propto \mathcal{O}(h)\, .
\end{align}
the $S^\prime$ is invariant.